# insert the exception error into the table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a code like this:

```
do $$
begin
    create table yyy(a int);
    create table yyy(a int); -- this will cause an error

    create table y(b varchar(250));

exception when others then 

    raise notice 'The transaction is in an uncommittable state. '
                 'Transaction was rolled back';

--insert into y select  -- This line doesn't work.  
    raise notice '% %', SQLERRM, SQLSTATE;
end;


$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

I want to insert the error caused into Y table.

how can I do this?

I want to insert `NOTICE:  relation "yyy" already exists 42P07` into the Y table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to create Table Y in a separated script, so it exists before the exception is raised.

```
create table y(b varchar(250));
```

You could execute your command in a separated block without the table Y creation. Something like this:

```
begin
    create table yyy(a int);
    create table yyy(a int); -- this will cause an error

exception when others then 
    raise notice 'The transaction is in an uncommittable state. '
             'Transaction was rolled back';
    insert into y(b) values('NOTICE:  relation "yyy" already exists 42P07');
    raise notice '% %', SQLERRM, SQLSTATE;
end;
```

Comment: `Insert into y(b) values select from raise notice '% %', SQLERRM, SQLSTATE;`  something like this I want.. the error message is runtime.

Comment: how about the following : Insert into y(b) values (SQLERRM || ' ' || SQLSTATE);